# Visual Studio 2015 - Can't get real time compile and edit and continue to work

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

What steps do I need to take to enable real time compilation and edit and continue? I have several MVC5 C# applications and the features just don't work.

I enabled "Just My Code" and checked "Enable Edit and Continue" in Debugging options. I even tried to reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: are you compiling your project to x86 platform ? I don't know in VS2015, but in older versions, this feature does not work under x64 projects

Comment: VS2015 supports 64-bit edit and continue along with 32-bit edit and continue.

Comment: I tried switching all projects to x86 anyway. Now I get "changes are not allowed while code is running."

Comment: Is the code running while you are trying to edit? Have you tried editing while paused at a breakpoint?

Comment: You have to have the code paused before you can edit. Also install the latest updates, we fixed a few bugs after we RTMed.

Comment: Hi, none of these worked unfortunately. I had to create a new project and copy source files over. Must have been some setting somewhere.

Comment: I wish we could find what setting that is. I'm having the same problem in MVC5, VS2015. All my code is in source control and I'd really rather not make a new copy of everything just to fix a glitch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I created a new project and copied source files over. It is now working as expected.

Must have been a setting somewhere that I wasn't able to locate.